# Using scanf %p UB

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

From the C11 Standard (draft): [7.21.6.2/12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p12):

> If **the input item is a value converted earlier during the same program
>   execution**, the pointer that results shall compare equal to that value;
>   otherwise the behavior of the %p conversion is undefined.

Can someone provide a code for this part of standard please. Can not understand the use of getting `%p` from input too.

Comment: If you have a pointer variable `p`, printf it using `%p` conversion, then copy, paste, and scanf using the same `%p` conversion into another pointer variable `q` in the same process, then `p==q`.

Comment: You don't want to for example `printf` out 8088's segmented pointer values like `5:abcd` out and scan them in on 386's flat architecture.

Comment: Note that a successful round trip of pointer--> text --> pointer will result in a pointer that "compare(s) equal to that value".  The original and final pointers may still have different bit encodings, but equivalent _values_, just like `+0.0 == -0.0`  Details depend on the platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, here is a small demo that uses string versions of input and output ([demo](http://ideone.com/ZQge52)):

```
int val = 123;
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "%p", (void*)&val);
printf("Original =%s\n", buf);
void *ptr;
sscanf(buf, "%p", &ptr);
printf("Read back=%p\n", ptr);
int *iPtr = ptr;
if (iPtr == &val) {
    printf("Pointers match\n");
}
```

The `sprintf` at the top writes the pointer to the output buffer; `sscanf` reads it back.

The string fed into `sscanf` matches exactly the string that was produced by `sprintf`, so the standard guarantees that `iPtr == &val` is going to evaluate to `true`, and the behavior is defined. Passing a string that does not match anything that has been produced by the same running program would be undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you certain the `int *ptr;` and `... (void**)&ptr);` is OK? I thought  `void*` and `int*` do not have to be the same size.  I'd expect `void *p; ... sscanf(buf, "%p", &p);`

Comment: @chux That's an excellent point, thank you very much! You are right, casts are good enough for `printf`, but not good enough for `scanf`. I edited the answer to account for that.

Comment: @chux Thanks again! It wasn't an illustration, it was a case of "too much C++".

Comment: It says the behavior of conversion is undefined not of program is there any difference here ?

Comment: @Sabrina If your program hits a statement with undefined conversion during its execution, the program is said to have an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(){
    int c =5;
    int *p;
    printf("Address of C: %p\n Please Enter the above address: " , &c);
    scanf("%p", &p);
    *p=10;
    printf("\nNew value of  C: %d", c);
}
```

You could manually set pointers via scanf.  Dangerous if you have a typo however.

Comment: Close but the type of pointer printed and scanned  is not quite right.